Making consistent read for columns using pd.read_excel
I want to read excel but most of my columns are in a cell which is a merge of 4-5 cells and some columns are divided across multiple cells ,
How can I perform pd.read_Excel() to have a consitent read so that i can get a row with the column names.
please find the snapshot of sample data where the last 2 columns are divided into multiple cells with first and last cell being empty 
